# Error in Mysql query using hibernate and java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Mysql query

```java
sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE userId = :userId AND deleteFlag = 0 "
                    + "AND YEAR(NOW()) = YEAR(CreatedDate) ");
            sql.append("ORDER BY Id ");

            query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString());
            query.addEntity(table_name.class);
            query.setParameter("userId", userId);
```

```
Error performing load command: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.scotts.beans.model.User#4127404]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$2.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:435) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:233) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1038) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:630) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:139) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:982) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:857) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at com.scotts.dao.impl.UserLawnProfileDAOImplV2.getLawnProfile(UserLawnProfileDAOImplV2.java:189) [classes:]
```

model

```java
public class UserProgramRecommendationV2 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Integer id;

    @Column(name="UserId")
    private Long userId;
}
```

check in data base all rows matches with that defined in model.

Comment: that doesn;t solve it @Alien

Comment: It is failing only in queries where there is Id filed, I don't know whats wrong.
and this started coming when I added an extra column in model.

Comment: @Column(name = "LawnCarePlanId")
private Integer lawnCarePlanId;
This was there is DB added in model mow @Alien

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211447/discussion-between-deepak-poojari-and-alien).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
User#4127404
```

Somewhere in the model you have a class `X` that have association to `User` with `id` `4127404`. There is not a `User` with such id in the database.

Comment: This might be the case.
 I have below relationship in model

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "UserId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private User user

can I make some changes to run it when userId in user doesn't exist.

Comment: @DeepakPoojari You need to use FetchType.LAZY.

Answer (score 0):

you use native query. check your database and name of UserId column. I think it's name is user_id, you should use this name in your query

Comment: The problem is not with other fields.
But when i use ID (order by ID) it breaks with above error.

Comment: and this queries run in mysql perfectly but not using hibernate. @fatemeakbari